# When submit an Oracle scheduler job (42/76 PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal) this error message received

Tags: oracle, plsql, job-scheduling

The error shows when submit the job inside a procedure, error message (42/76     PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal) shows. Job config is showing following.

```
DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (
    job_number => v_job_ID + 1,
    what       => 'BEGIN'|| v_query ||'END',
    next_date  => TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE, 'SUN')) + 2.5/24, -- 2:30 AM,
    interval   => 'NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), ''SUN'') + 2.5/24',
    comments   => 'Job to run every sunday at 2:30 AM',
    no_parse   => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are various mistakes you've made, but I don't see what causes error you mentioned.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_job_id  NUMBER := 0;
  3     v_query   VARCHAR2 (100) := 'null;';
  4  BEGIN
  5     v_job_id := v_job_id + 1;
  6     DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT (job        => v_job_ID,
  7                      what       => 'BEGIN ' || v_query || ' END',
  8                      next_date  => TRUNC (NEXT_DAY (SYSDATE, 'SUN')) + 2.5 / 24, -- 2:30 AM,
  9                      interval   => 'NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE), ''SUN'') + 2.5/24',
 10                      --comments    => 'Job to run every sunday at 2:30 AM',
 11                      no_parse   => TRUE);
 12
 13     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_job_id);
 14  END;
 15  /
2983346

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

- you can't put `v_job_ID + 1` into `submit`; calculate it *elsewhere* (see line #5), but - that's in vain because `DBMS_JOB` **returns** job `ID`; it is not that you can set it yourself (see result after line #15)
- `what` requires a space between begin and the command itself, otherwise you'll get syntax error
- `comments` can't be used in `submit` (check syntax)
- your database speaks English, doesn't it? Mine doesn't, so I altered session so that your code works in my database. Consider not to use day names as code might *break* in other databases
- you didn't specify database version you use; nowadays, in *modern* versions, `dbms_job` is here just for backward compatibility. Consider switching to `dbms_scheduler`

Comment: I have modified all the mistakes in my script, yeah it is working fine now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And i have one confusion also, is this job run right after I call the procedure which use these jobs or it is just schedule and execute only every Sunday within the mentioned date??

Comment: You're welcome. It'll run as scheduled.

Comment: can we make this not run when i execute because I need to execute job only sunday. is it do able to configure